# Unable to compile sfml with imgui using makefile

Tags: sfml, imgui

I was trying to compile a project into executable which uses sfml and imgui
I used **[imgui-sfml](https://github.com/eliasdaler/imgui-sfml)** a third-party library which makes it possible

I also followed the tutorial **[ImGui+SFML Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2YS5WJTeKpI&t=13s)** and setup the folder structure according to that but instead of using **visual studio** I wrote my own **Makefile** for compiling it

**[Github Repository from YouTube Tutorial](https://github.com/VictorGordan/SFML-ImGUI)**
I cloned it and just moved the dlls in source directory to bin because once the program is compiled it needs those to run

**Folder Structure**:https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ1o9.png

**Makefile**

```
libs=-lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-system -lopengl32 
lib_path=-L./libraries/lib
includes=-I./libraries/include -I./imgui/include
o_files=main.o imgui.o imgui-SFML.o imgui_tables.o imgui_draw.o imgui_widgets.o
cmds=-g -Wall -std=c++17

all:main.o imgui.o
    g++ $(o_files) $(cmds) -o main $(includes) $(lib_path) $(libs) #❌ gives error
main.o:main.cpp
    g++ main.cpp $(cmds) -c $(includes) #✅ success compiling
imgui.o:
    g++ ./imgui/src/* $(cmds) -c $(includes) #✅ success compiling

clean:
    rm -r *.o
```

**Running the Makefile in Terminal**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2wcW.png

**Errors**

```
g++ main.cpp -g -Wall -std=c++17 -c -I./libraries/include -I./imgui/include
g++ ./imgui/src/* -g -Wall -std=c++17 -c -I./libraries/include -I./imgui/include
g++ main.o imgui.o imgui-SFML.o imgui_tables.o imgui_draw.o imgui_widgets.o -g -Wall -std=c++17 -o ./bin/main.exe -I./libraries/include -I./imgui/include -L./libraries/lib -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-system -lopengl32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: main.o: in function `main':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6StringC1EPKcRKSt6locale'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf9VideoModeC1Ejjj'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderWindowC1ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf11CircleShapeC1Efy'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5ColorC1Ehhhh'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5Shape12setFillColorERKNS_5ColorE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:23: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf13Transformable9setOriginEff'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf13Transformable11setPositionEff'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5ClockC1Ev'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf6Window6isOpenEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6Window9pollEventERNS_5EventE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6Window5closeEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:36: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5Clock7restartEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:47: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf11CircleShape9setRadiusEf'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:48: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf13Transformable9setOriginEff'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:49: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf11CircleShape13setPointCountEy'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:50: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5ColorC1Ehhhh'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:50: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5Shape12setFillColorERKNS_5ColorE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:57: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5ColorC1Ehhhh'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:57: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderTarget5clearERKNS_5ColorE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:59: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderStates7DefaultE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:59: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderTarget4drawERKNS_8DrawableERKNS_12RenderStatesE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:61: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6Window7displayEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: main.o: in function `sf::CircleShape::~CircleShape()':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./libraries/include/SFML/Graphics/CircleShape.hpp:41: undefined reference to `__imp__ZTVN2sf11CircleShapeE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./libraries/include/SFML/Graphics/CircleShape.hpp:41: undefined reference to `__imp__ZTVN2sf11CircleShapeE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./libraries/include/SFML/Graphics/CircleShape.hpp:41: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5ShapeD2Ev'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `ImGui::SFML::Init(sf::Window&, sf::Vector2<float> const&, bool)':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:260: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf7TextureD1Ev'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:262: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf7TextureC1Ev'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:270: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf6Window8hasFocusEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `ImGui::SFML::Update(sf::Window&, sf::RenderTarget&, sf::Time)':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:370: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5Touch6isDownEj'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:370: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5Touch11getPositionEjRKNS_6WindowE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:374: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5Mouse11getPositionERKNS_6WindowE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:379: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6Window21setMouseCursorVisibleEb'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `ImGui::SFML::Update(sf::Vector2<int> const&, sf::Vector2<float> const&, sf::Time)':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:387: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf4Time9asSecondsEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:393: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5Mouse11setPositionERKNS_7Vector2IiEE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:398: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5Touch6isDownEj'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:399: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5Mouse15isButtonPressedENS0_6ButtonE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `ImGui::SFML::Render(sf::RenderTarget&)':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:443: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderTarget13resetGLStatesEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:444: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderTarget12pushGLStatesEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:447: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderTarget11popGLStatesEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `ImGui::SFML::Shutdown()':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:459: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf7TextureD1Ev'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:465: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6CursorD1Ev'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `ImGui::SFML::UpdateFontTexture()':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:483: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf7Texture6createEjj'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:484: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf7Texture6updateEPKh'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:486: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf7Texture15getNativeHandleEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `ImGui::Image(sf::Texture const&, sf::Color const&, sf::Color const&)':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:540: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf7Texture7getSizeEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `ImGui::Image(sf::Texture const&, sf::Vector2<float> const&, sf::Color const&, sf::Color const&)':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:545: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf7Texture15getNativeHandleEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `ImGui::Image(sf::RenderTexture const&, sf::Vector2<float> const&, sf::Color const&, sf::Color const&)':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:560: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf13RenderTexture10getTextureEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:560: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf7Texture15getNativeHandleEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `ImGui::Image(sf::Sprite const&, sf::Color const&, sf::Color const&)':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:571: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf6Sprite15getGlobalBoundsEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `ImGui::Image(sf::Sprite const&, sf::Vector2<float> const&, sf::Color const&, sf::Color const&)':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:577: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf6Sprite10getTextureEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:584: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf7Texture7getSizeEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:585: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf6Sprite14getTextureRectEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:590: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf7Texture15getNativeHandleEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `ImGui::ImageButton(sf::Texture const&, int, sf::Color const&, sf::Color const&)':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:600: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf7Texture7getSizeEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `ImGui::ImageButton(sf::Texture const&, sf::Vector2<float> const&, int, sf::Color const&, sf::Color const&)':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:606: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf7Texture15getNativeHandleEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `ImGui::ImageButton(sf::RenderTexture const&, sf::Vector2<float> const&, int, sf::Color const&, sf::Color const&)':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:623: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf13RenderTexture10getTextureEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:623: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf7Texture15getNativeHandleEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `ImGui::ImageButton(sf::Sprite const&, int, sf::Color const&, sf::Color const&)':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:635: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf6Sprite15getGlobalBoundsEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `ImGui::ImageButton(sf::Sprite const&, sf::Vector2<float> const&, int, sf::Color const&, sf::Color const&)':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:642: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf6Sprite10getTextureEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:649: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf7Texture7getSizeEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:650: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf6Sprite14getTextureRectEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:655: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf7Texture15getNativeHandleEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `getConnectedJoystickId':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:882: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf8Joystick11isConnectedEj'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `updateJoystickActionState':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:914: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf8Joystick15isButtonPressedEjj'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `updateJoystickDPadState':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:919: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf8Joystick15getAxisPositionEjNS0_4AxisE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:922: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf8Joystick15getAxisPositionEjNS0_4AxisE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `updateJoystickLStickState':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:933: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf8Joystick15getAxisPositionEjNS0_4AxisE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:936: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf8Joystick15getAxisPositionEjNS0_4AxisE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `setClipboardText':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:957: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf9Clipboard9setStringERKNS_6StringE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `getClipboardText':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:961: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf9Clipboard9getStringEv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:961: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf6String6toUtf8B5cxx11Ev'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `loadMouseCursor':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:967: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6CursorC1Ev'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:969: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6Cursor14loadFromSystemENS0_4TypeE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `updateMouseCursor':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:977: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6Window21setMouseCursorVisibleEb'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:979: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6Window21setMouseCursorVisibleEb'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./imgui/src/imgui-SFML.cpp:983: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6Window14setMouseCursorERKNS_6CursorE'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: imgui-SFML.o: in function `sf::String sf::String::fromUtf8<char const*>(char const*, char const*)':
D:\Projects\c++\sfml_imgui/./libraries/include/SFML/System/String.inl:30: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6StringC1Ev'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:8: all] Error 1
```

**Note: All the object files(.o) are generated successfully**
*If you need more details please do ask*

Comment: Were your libraries compiled for mingw? msvc binaries will not work

Comment: [https://github.com/VictorGordan/SFML-ImGUI](https://github.com/VictorGordan/SFML-ImGUI) contains binaries for msvc not mingw. These will not work. You can't usually use c++ libraries with different compilers than the library was built with. My advice is to switch to use msys2 to install your mingw and use the package manager in msys2 to install the proper binaries for sfml: [https://www.msys2.org/](https://www.msys2.org/)

Comment: **IT WORKED!**
**Thank You Very Much** All I did was download the x64 bit compiled binaries from [SFML Official Website](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/) and replace them with the one before and now it runs 